# Join overlapping objects/meshes into one surface in Blender

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I have a lot of spheres imported from the [pdb-import plugin](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Import-Export/PDB), which make up a molecule. I chose the radii of the spheres large enough, that all individual spheres overlap somewhere with others and this should form one closed object.

I cannot find a single tool to merge/weld/join/whatever the faces where they overlap to form just one uniform mesh surface without hidden faces on the "inside" of other objects.

The *Mesh* > *Faces* > *Intersect* and a simple *Object* > *Join* do not seem to do what I want to achieve.

For reference concerning the pdb-plugin, I have done *Apply* > *Make Dupliverts Real* and *Object* > *Convert* > *Mesh* as suggested.

Comment: `Join` will merge them into a single mesh where `intersect` can then cut the faces where they intersect. Then try `Select -> Interior Faces`

Answer (score 1):

I would use the boolean modifier to union them together.

Lets say I have 3 overlapping spheres i want to make into one, connected object.
[image: spheres]

Select one sphere, and create two boolean modifiers, both set to `Union`, with the other spheres as the objects:
[image: boolean]

Hit apply, and you can now delete the original two spheres. the third sphere with the boolean modifiers should now be one mesh that makes up all 3 spheres:

[image: done]